# PPPoE connection not configuring properly

Tags: networking, pppoe

I've looked through different posts about this type of issue but am not able to find a working solution. After running pppoeconf in terminal the option to connect through the configuration was taken. I then typed in 'plog' out of curiosity to check the network connection status.
Here's what I got back:

[image: log output]

I rebooted but the network configuration at startup didn't initialize at first, was prompted that 60 more seconds would be devoted to the task and the computer then continued the startup process. Ran pppoeconf again to make sure I got the info right, ran the 'plog' and got the same response. I can't use network manager. I'm stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The logs clearly indicate that the PPP CHAP authentication has failed. How have you verified that the CHAP credentials you configured are valid?

Take a look at the [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ADSLPPPoE#The_chap-secrets_File)

Does your `/etc/ppp/chap-secrets` have the username and password supplied by the ISP?

If you don't know what the login credentials for your ISP are - have you ever used an off-the-shelf PPPoE modem with this ISP? Perhaps you can view your login/password there.

Comment: I don't know what that means. I was frustrated earlier when I posted and had to walk away from the machine. I'll have another go at it tomorrow.

Comment: The credentials (i.e. username and password) are what the ISPs gives you the login to your Internet access service. Updated my answer.

Comment: I contacted the service provider and got the correct password. They recently underwent system upgrades and some customers have had to deal with their password being reset. The direct connection is now working. That said, I'm now trying to install network manager back on the machine but have unmet dependencies. I ran `sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get upgrade, sudo dpkg --configure -a, sudo apt-get -f install` but there are still unmet dependencies. How can I resolve this?

Comment: I tried installing the package wicd-kde through synaptic and got this as a response
_wicd-kde:
 Depends: kde-runtime  but it is not installable
 Depends: libkdecore5 (>=4:4.4.5) but it is not installable
 Depends: libkdeui5 (>=4:4.4.5) but it is not installable
 Depends: libknotifyconfig4 (>=4:4.4.5) but it is not installable
 Depends: libsolid4 (>=4:4.4.5) but it is not installable_

Doesn't look promising :/

Comment: Try using aptitude in place of apt-get - it has some more sophisticated conflict/dependency resolution methods. I'd stick with installing network-manager package first.